# MySQL don't start (ubuntu): [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option '--skip-locking'

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, webmin

I can't start MYSQL.

I changed a parameter in WEBMIN in the main mysql configuration:

```
SKIP LOCKING OF TABLE FILES?... the original value was "NO", and I changed to "YES"
```

This is the LOG file:

```
131026  1:12:27 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
131026  1:12:27 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
131026  1:12:27 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
131026  1:12:27 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
131026  1:12:27 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
131026  1:12:27 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
131026  1:12:27 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
131026  1:12:27 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
131026  1:12:27  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
131026  1:12:28 InnoDB: 5.5.34 started; log sequence number 9992525
131026  1:12:28 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option '--skip-locking'
131026  1:12:28 [ERROR] Aborting

131026  1:12:28  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
131026  1:12:29  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 9992525
131026  1:12:29 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

The problem is in [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option '--skip-locking'.

So, my file "my.cnf" is good, because it says this:

```
[mysqld]



user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
```

Please I need help tp restart mysql.

Thank you soo much for your time and help

Comment: What is your version of *MySQL* ?

Comment: My version is Mysql 5.5

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your MySQL doesn't support this flag. Have you tried to change this option back in webmin? If it doesn't help, try to look at /etc/init.d/mysqld and /etc/default/mysqld (I'm not sure about filenames). Look there for args for daemon.

Comment: I tried to change the value on webmin, but it's imposible because the server don't start, so, webmin can't manage the options.

Comment: As I already said,  try to look at /etc/default/mysqld (I'm not sure about filenames). Look there for args for daemon.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to open this, actually it was the first file to looked, but i cant open it with an editor, gedit or other.

Comment: Try to be more informative and I'll be more usefull :)
Why you can't open? Did you try root? Open terminal and exec: `sudo -i`, `cd /etc/defaults`, `ls`, find the conf for mysql and open it by `nano <file>`. Find and remove your flag there.
Or try to run MySQL manualy with out this flag and try to find it in webmin after that.

Answer (score 0):

Ouich! So bad! The flag skip-locking was renamed skip-external-locking in MySQL 4.0.3 (see [this list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/news-4-0-3.html)), and untill now no one has told the guys at webmin to change it.

By the way this is the default behaviour, and this flag doesn't change anything, see actual MySQL doc [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_external-locking). May be that's why no one bothered about this.